# Why is there a margin difference on Chrome for Mac vs Chrome for PC?

Tags: css, google-chrome, navigation

I was charged with the task of fixing a navigation bar issue where its display was 1px lower than it should be.

After reviewing the website I could not find the issue that was being reported until I checked on a Mac. Firefox, Safari etc were fine on Mac but Chrome was the browser that had it displaying incorrectly.

Any fix I have attempted to apply moves the navigation bar 1px out of position. [Navigation bar misplaced](http://ct-social.com/ctsdev/odyssey/)

Answer (score 0):

reset.css is your answer. I don't know the technical part of why Chrome is different but this is the best I can come up with.

Comment: reset.css is not my answer. :(